# split all list columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` with many columns

```
df=
                                                    c1\
2015-01-01  [50.4750711276, 50.4750711276, 50.4750711276]   
2015-01-02  [50.5349107929, 50.5349107929, 50.5349107929]     

                                                   c2
2015-01-01  [33.5322374641, 33.5322374641, 33.5322374641]  
2015-01-02  [33.4770757092, 33.4770757092, 33.4770757092]
```

I would like to split each column into columns containing the single elements of the lists. Like (for c1)

```
          0          1          2
0  50.475071  50.475071  50.475071
1  50.534911  50.534911  50.534911
```

I can do

```
pd.DataFrame(df.c1.values.tolist()).add_prefix('code_')
```

but how to do it for all the columns at the same time and being able to add a prefix based on the name of the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
comp = [pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist(), index=df.index).add_suffix('_code_' + x) 
         for x in df.columns]
df = pd.concat(comp, axis=1)
print (df)
            0_code_c1  1_code_c1  2_code_c1  0_code_c2  1_code_c2  2_code_c2
2015-01-01  50.475071  50.475071  50.475071  33.532237  33.532237  33.532237
2015-01-02  50.534911  50.534911  50.534911  33.477076  33.477076  33.477076
```

EDIT:

```
names = list('ABC')
comp = [pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist(), index=df.index, columns=names).add_suffix('_' + x)
         for i, x in enumerate(df.columns)]
df = pd.concat(comp, axis=1)
print (df)
                 A_c1       B_c1       C_c1       A_c2       B_c2       C_c2
2015-01-01  50.475071  50.475071  50.475071  33.532237  33.532237  33.532237
2015-01-02  50.534911  50.534911  50.534911  33.477076  33.477076  33.477076
```

Comment: can I replace the int_ which is automatically added to each column name at beginning? I have a list of strings same len as the columns of df